# Do I need to pay for an Oracle EE license for OAS 7 RCU Installation?

Tags: oracle, license, enterprise-edition

I need to install OAS (Oracle Analytics Server) 7, but this version needs an Oracle RDBMS EE for the RCU. Is this free of charge, like the recovery catalog is for example, or do I need a full license?

Comment: Licensing quesitons are off-topic on this site. Talk to your Oracle sales rep.